# Cordova StatusBar Plugin Keyboard overlapping

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, statusbar

I installed this package : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/

to hide statusbar on android.

I am using this command : `StatusBar.hide();` in first page's deviceReady event.

It works well, but when i try to focus some inputs, soft keyboard overlaps on input.

If i remove hide command from my js, there is no problem.

Is this a bug ?

edit :

- I tried to change fullscreen preference to `false` in config.xml
- I tried to change `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest.xml.

**edit 2 :**

I want to hide on IOS too. But i tried for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these preferences in your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

**edit :**

Another way you can try

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

after that add show listener to it.

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', function () {
    // Describe your logic which will be run each time keyboard is shown.
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.activeElement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
    }, 100);
});
```

**note :- Tested in chrome and safari**

Comment: nope, it isn't work with this plugin. If i disable plugin, it works.